# Python TypeError: 'list' object is not callable with a dict dictionary, if boolean

Tags: python, list, dictionary, callable, callable-object

I have a dictionary that converts an index number to a node name.  I am trying to check if the name is already in a list.  I get an error list 'object not callable'. An image of my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soGAb.png) is attached.

Comment: You should just copy and paste your code to your question, this makes it much easier for people to contribute.

Comment: Ok wait, i am converting your image to text with my super `ocr` app to test it in my computer... [like @chthonicdaemon said; you should copy and paste your code here]

Comment: thank you - removing () worked.  sorry thought photo would display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `visited()` to `visited`...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line,

```
if index2node[index] not in visited()
```

From the below line, it seems that you are treating `visited` as a callable object i.e trying to call it.

But look at the line,

```
visited = list()
```

So, `visited` is a list and isn't a callable object. It has no `__call__` method. To check this, do:

```
print hasattr(visited, '__call__')
```

In your case, as you only want to check an element in  a list, do this:

```
if index2node[index] not in visited:
```